# How can i transplant old src from groovy to hydro?

Tags: ros-groovy, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone, maybe some Ros Kong. I'm a beginner in Ros and Ubuntu, but someone who know well of Ros in my tutor's Lab has graduated to another University  and leave us amount of sources. Now I'd like to rebuild these sources which written in groovy and I'm using Hydro. Should I change which part in the source so that I can run their sources?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187360/how-can-i-transplant-old-src-from-groovy-to-hydro?/) by [putuotingchan](https://answers.ros.org/users/15081/putuotingchan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-07-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the most part, packages that worked in Groovy should continue to work in Hydro. I would try them first without any changes, and troubleshoot any issues as they arise.

If you run into specific issues or trouble compiling, you can update your question with the specific error you're seeing or ask a new question.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For this problem there is the [Migration Guide](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration). Check out if anything in there pertains to your code and follow the changes noted. Everything else should be fine.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2